# ДевИца или дЕвица

Tags: фонетика

В русском языке присутствуют оба варианта: "Красна дЕвица", но "на тебе, краса-девица,/Я теперь хочу жениться...". В чем разница и почему такое разночтение в ударениях?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильное ударение - дев**И**ца, -ы; но в фольклорных текстах в соотвествии с народно-поэтической традицией: красна д**е**вица, д**е**вица-красавица.